# How to persistently set a variable in Windows 7 from a batch file?

Tags: windows, path, batch-file, environment-variables

I am trying to set the PATH environment variable in windows 7 using a bat-file; however it does not seem to work.

I am using this windows command:

```
set PATH=%cd%;%path%
pause
```

However it only appears to be valid for this cmd instance.  I want it to be permanent, since I first set the PATH and then run a program which needs to locate the libraries in that folder.

Comment: If you change into that directory, won't your program pick them up? Maybe you can solve this by sidestepping the problem entirely?

Comment: @Jon isn't it dangerous to rely on working directory for DLL search? Best of all is to put DLLs in same directory as .exe and then there's no room for error.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I wouldn't say it's "dangerous". In any case, that decision has already been made by Microsoft and/or the program's author, so no changing that. Your answer is good (in fact I am your +1), but maybe this could be solved in 30 seconds instead?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use setx.exe instead of set.

```
setx PATH "%cd%;%path%;"
pause
```

Note that this sets the path for all future cmd instances, but *not* for the current one.  If you need that, also run your original set command.

UPDATE: The second parameter needs to be quoted if it contains spaces (which %path% always has).  Be warned that if the last character in your %path% is a backslash, it will escape the trailing quote and the last path entry will stop working.  I get around that by appending a semicolon before the closing quote.

If you don't want to risk getting ";;;;;;" at the end of your path after repeated runs, then instead strip any trailing backslash from the %path% variable before setting, and it will work correctly.

Comment: @KaiserJohaan: Note also the absence of `=`, as the two commands look similar and the syntax might easily be confused.

Comment: I'm getting this in return: "ERROR: Invalid syntax. Default option is not allowed more tan 2 times" What does that imply?

Comment: Okay, can't link to the thread with the trailing backslash discussion (Why CAN'T posts contain that content, you stupid website?!).  Do a search on "setx path spaces" to find the thread I was talking about.

Comment: BE Careful if you do SETX PATH "%PATH%;C:\My\App" /M because the %PATH% variable expands to the user path + the system path, which could make the entire %PATH% greater than 1024 characters, which is the limit for expansion and it might duplicate some entries. A better way is to get the literal value from the PATH command and then set a literal value using SETX.

Comment: Wizlb, thats a great point, but when I do set %PATH% or echo %PATH% I only see the system variables on my laptop. Are you sure of that?

Comment: @wizlb good warn, it reads `WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.` it screwed it up.

Comment: setx will set the variables for the user running the command. To set at the machine level use switch `\M`. Full command should look like  `setx \M http_proxy http://myproxyserver.com:80`

Answer (score 21):

If you want to do it in a batch file, use the **reg** command to change the path value in the registry at the HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment key.

Something like:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "%path%;c:\newpath"
```

Check that the path in the %path% variable matches the system path.

Comment: this is a better idea when your path will go over 1024 characters.

Comment: I had to restart the computer to apply the changes.

Comment: note that when you use `%path%` it will expand any variables that happen to be in `%path%`. I think you can maybe use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` to prevent this.

Answer (score 18):

As wizlb noted, doing

```
setx PATH "%cd%;%path%;" -m
```

will copy local env to system env, and without -m it will copy system env to user env. Neither is desirable. In order to accurately edit only one part of registry (system or user, system in my below example) you need to do this:

```
for /F "tokens=2* delims= " %%f IN ('reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path ^| findstr /i path') do set OLD_SYSTEM_PATH=%%g
setx.exe PATH "%OLD_SYSTEM_PATH%;%OTHER_STUFF%;" -m
```

Credit for the solution goes to http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntregistry.php

Comment: Great answer! The others solutions will expand the variables to costants (SystemRoot, JAVA_HOME etc). Yours will preserve them

Comment: One caveat is that you may have to reboot windows before changes take effect everywhere. I forgot where exactly it's a problem, so if you see anything weird just reboot and try again.

Comment: Get rid of ` delims= ` in your code.  On my (retired) WinXP `reg query` delimites items by **TAB**s, not with spaces! In typical output line we can identify (after four leading spaces): _value name_ **TAB** _value type_ **TAB** _value_

Comment: +1 for -m. One of my application (running an application as a service) required me to set system variable (not the user variable). Turns out, I was missing -m switch.

Answer (score 12):

To do this properly I think you really need to go beyond a simple batch file.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) states:

> To programmatically add or modify system environment variables, add them to the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment** registry key, then broadcast a [**`WM_SETTINGCHANGE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message with *lParam* set to the string "Environment". This allows applications, such as the shell, to pick up your updates.

First of all you won't be able to write to that key without a UAC elevation prompt. That's best arranged by adding the appropriate manifest to an executable file. Secondly, broadcasting `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` isn't simple from a batch file.

In your position I'd write a short and simple console app to do the job.

Comment: you may be interested in the utility called [SendMessage](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/SendMessage.html), to broadcast your `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, from stefanstools sf net.  [source discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20848009/611007) wonders whether native vbscript would have some API wrappers lurking out there for this purpose.

Answer (score 4):

A simple (may be better) solution is to use PathMgr.cmd

Down the pathmgr_1.0.2.zip in https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Batch-Script-To-Manage-7d0ef21e

Unzip and put the pathmgr.cmd in the same folder as your batch file, then in your batch file write these two lines:

```
call pathmgr.cmd /del %cd% /y
call pathmgr.cmd /add %cd% /y
```

This will:

1) only update the user variable PATH, 
2) will not include system PATH multiple times

You can also run the batch file multiple times, and it will only include your current path ONCE in the PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I want to create a System Environment Variable called "ZIP_PROGRAM" and I want to point it to the executable at path "reg add C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe

I will perform following at DOS Prompt:

Step1: execute following code
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v ZIP_PROGRAM /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" /f

Step2: Log Off then Login

Step3: Open DOS Prompt and execute: "set z"  and you should be able to see the System Environment Variable update

Answer (score 0):

Use This command
**setx PATH "%PATH%;%MVN_HOME%\bin\"**

Anyways it wont be set in current session you need to use

**set PATH="%PATH%;%MVN_HOME%\bin\"**