# Setting path using setx removed current references

Tags: path, setx

I was trying to set my path using setx /M PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts" as given in an answer [How do I add to the Windows PATH variable using setx? Having weird problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287379/how-do-i-add-to-the-windows-path-variable-using-setx-having-weird-problems). However this appears to remove all my current path setting and the new one doesnt work either. Is there any way I can revert back to my old settings?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/523688/deleted-path-environment-variable-how-to-restore This might help?

Comment: I am on windows 8 and I think that feature is removed

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/874687/how-to-restore-the-environment-variable-in-win-8-1 Just found this. Sorry if it didn't help you either.