# How to see if a string contains a substring using batch

Tags: string, file, batch-file, substring

Currently trying to see if a string, in this case the current line of a text file, contains a substring `#`. I am new to batch, so I am not sure exactly how I would do something like this. Here is the code
`set substring = #`

```
for /f "delims=," %%a in (Text.txt) do (
    set string = %%a

    //check substring method        

    echo %string%

)
```

Comment: Do not put _SPACEs_ around the `=` at the `set` command line, because they become part of the variable name and the (string) value otherwise...

Comment: @aschipfl OK, I already took that line out anyway.

Comment: I just saw that this issue is dealt with in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34077870/5047996) anyway...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
echo %%a|find "substring" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (echo found)
```

Batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Comment: I do not want to print out %%a|find "substring" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (echo notfound) else (echo found), just only print the string if it does not contain #

Comment: Sorry- my crystal ball must be on the blink again. Replace `notfound` with `%%a` and lose the `else` clause. These commands must be within the `for` loop.

Comment: Alright, it works now. Is there a way to do it without it printing out the code?

Comment: First line of a batch file is normally `@echo off` which suppresses the code display.

Comment: @Magoo u should use `findstr` instead of `find`

Comment: @raypixar: Interesting assertion. Do you have a reason for advocating `findstr` over `find`?

Comment: @Magoo i've tested your code with `find` it did not work. it only works with `findstr`

Comment: @raypixar: Sadly, you've not provided sufficient data to analyse the problem. What string did you attempt to find within what textstring for instance - and what was the result? I **Strongly** suspect that you have installed *Cygwin* or some other \*nix emulator, which overrides Windows' `find` utility with the nixy locate-a-file function. Under those circumstances, *any* Windows batch file which expects Windows' `find` will fail unless you explicitly specify the name of the `find` executable (Usually %windir%\System32\find.exe for 32-bit systems)

Comment: @magoo sorry my bad, u are searching in a file ? I was searching in string

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `find`, you can use string substitution, like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "substring=#"
for /f "delims=," %%a in (Text.txt) do (
    set "string=%%a"
    if "!string:%substring%=!"=="!string!" (
        rem string with substring removed equals the original string,
        rem so it does not contain substring; therefore, output it:
        echo(!string!
    )
)
endlocal
```

This approach uses delayed environment variable expansion. Type `setlocal /?` in command prompt to find out how to enable it, and `set /?` to see how it works (read variables like `!string!` instead of `%string%`) and what it means. `set /?` also describes the string substitution syntax.

Comment: See my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34078434/4): I accidently did not use delayed expansion for `string` although I described it...

Answer (score 1):

I had to create a function:

Use it as:

```
SearchText = "Why does the purple cow jump over the moon?"
SearchTerm = "Purple"
CALL:checkIfStringCotainsText "%SearchText%" "%SearchTerm%" RESULT
IF %RESULT%==true(
    ECHO Text Found!
) ELSE (
    ECHO Text NOT Found.
)
```

Remember it is not case sensitive by default. Add the word true to the end of the Call if you would like to be case sensitive such as:

```
SearchText = "Why does the purple cow jump over the moon?"
SearchTerm = "Purple"
CALL:checkIfStringCotainsText "%SearchText%" "%SearchTerm%" RESULT true
REM # Returns false because Purple is capitalized
```

And these Functions to the bottom of your Batch File.

```
:FUNCTIONS
@REM FUNCTIONS AREA
GOTO:EOF
EXIT /B

:checkIfStringCotainsText 
@REM # CHECKS IF A STRING CONTAINS A SUBSTRING
@REM # Returns the %3 as either set to true or false
@REM # Not case sensetive by defualt. But can be set to case sensetive buying adding true as the fourth paramater
@REM # For example: CALL:checkIfStringCotainsText "Whats up SLY Fox?"   "fox"          RESULT              true
@REM #                                                 SearchText     SearchTerm 
   true-or-false    CaseSensetive?
@Rem # Will check if "Whats up SLY Fox?"" contains the text "fox"
@REM # Then check the result with: if %RESULT%==true (Echo Text Found) Else (Text Not Found)
@REM # Remember do not add %RESULT% use only RESULT .Do not add % around RESULT when calling the function.
@REM # Only add % around RESULT when checking the result.
@REM # Make sure to add "SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" to the top of your Batch File! This is important!
@REM # Make sure you use quotes around SearchText and SearchTerm. For example "SearchText" not SearchText.
@REM # This is because if there is a space inside the SearchText, each space will make it look like a new parameter



SET SearchString=%~1
SET SearchTerm=%~2
@REM #Check if Case Senseitive
IF [%~4]==[true] (
    @REM if %~4 is not set to anything, treat it as the default as false
    @REM - Do nothing as FindStr is normally case sensetive
) ELSE (
    @REM Change both the text and search-term both to lowercase.
    CALL:LCase SearchString SearchString
    CALL:LCase SearchTerm SearchTerm

)
@set containsText=false
@echo DEBUG: Searching for ^|%~2^| inside ^|%~1^|
@echo "!SearchString!" | find "!SearchTerm!" > nul && if errorlevel 0 (set containsText=true)
SET %3=!containsText!
@GOTO:EOF


:LCase
:UCase
@REM Converts Text to Upper or Lower Case
@REM Brad Thone robvanderwoudeDOTcom
:: Converts to upper/lower case variable contents
:: Syntax: CALL :UCase _VAR1 _VAR2
:: Syntax: CALL :LCase _VAR1 _VAR2
:: _VAR1 = Variable NAME whose VALUE is to be converted to upper/lower case
:: _VAR2 = NAME of variable to hold the converted value
:: Note: Use variable NAMES in the CALL, not values (pass "by reference")
SET _UCase=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
SET _LCase=a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
SET _Lib_UCase_Tmp=!%1!
IF /I "%0"==":UCase" SET _Abet=%_UCase%
IF /I "%0"==":LCase" SET _Abet=%_LCase%
FOR %%Z IN (%_Abet%) DO SET _Lib_UCase_Tmp=!_Lib_UCase_Tmp:%%Z=%%Z!
SET %2=%_Lib_UCase_Tmp%
GOTO:EOF
```

And remember you MUST add "SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION" to the top of your batch file or else none of this will work properly.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@REM # Remember to add this to the top of your batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Function to return "TRUE/FALSE".

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/find

```
@ECHO OFF
SET Str=Hello

::SET SubStr=el
SET SubStr=EL
::SET SubStr=eZ

CALL :SUBSTRINGCHECK %Str% %SubStr% RESULT
ECHO %RESULT%
PAUSE

:SUBSTRINGCHECK
SET RESULT=FALSE
SET Str=%~1
SET SubStr=%~2
CALL :reset_error
ECHO "%Str%" | FIND /i "%SubStr%" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
 Set RESULT=TRUE
)
SET %3=%RESULT%
exit /b

:reset_error
exit /b 0
```