# Batch script to delete files only from specific sub-folders

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The following batch script deletes all `.exe` files recursively:

```
del *.exe /s
```

Is it possible to recursively delete files, but only if they are in a specific sub-folder e.g. `Debug`? `.exe` files in other folders should not be deleted.

Tried all of the following, but the syntax is not correct:

```
del Debug\*.exe /s
del *Debug\*.exe /s
del *\Debug\*.exe /s
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the suggestion from Dominique's answer and [this question about searching strings from the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34077831/how-to-see-if-a-string-contains-a-substring-using-batch), the following achieves what I need:

```
set "TargetPath=C:\some\folder"
pushd "%TargetPath%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir *.exe /s /b') do (
    echo %%~fa | find "Debug" > nul
    if !ERRORLEVEL! EQU 0 (del "%%~fa" /s)
    rem Note: Quotation marks required for possible spaces in paths
)
popd
```

Comment: plus one for writing your answer.