# How to "install" sqlite3 on my Windows 10 computer?

Tags: windows, sqlite

So I wanted to get started on Ruby on Rails because it sounds like fun but as I reached part 3.1 over [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) I ran into some problems.

First I just attempted "sqlite3 --version" in the "ruby cmd" and it came up with: "'sqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." So I attempted to just install the sqlite ruby gem and it did that just fine but as I typed "sqlite3 --version", same story. So I just figured you needed to install the thing your self.

So after I downloaded the "Precompiled Binaries for Windows" (64-bit DLL (x64) for SQLite version 3.11.1.) over [here](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) I moved the .dll and .def files to my system32 folder, launched CMD as admin and typed regsvr32 sqlite3.dll I get this error message: "The module "C:\WINDOWS\System32\sqlite3.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DIIRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "C:\WINDOWS\System32\sqlite3.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

I did a lot of googleing and talked with microsoft support and nothing helped. So im hopeing someone can help me out here. Thanks in advance :)

PS: My PC is "Windows 10 pro" 64 bit. If it matters.

Comment: Did you add SQLite3 to your path? You can try putting the three SQLite files in their own directory and adding that dir to the path.

Comment: This is why you should always develop on a UNIX system. What binaries are you using OP? Bitnami Ruby stack?

Comment: You should always provide full path if files are no un PATH variable, and I'm pretty sure you don't need to regsvr32 sqlite3.dll as it's not a COM object, it's just a plain dynamic library, if it's in system path or in your current path (not sure about this part) it should be found by the executable.

Comment: @MarsAtomic my path? Im sorry im very new to this. Ive seen PATH mentioned a few times and I have no clue :/

Comment: @Meshpi Im sorry I dont understand your question. I have no clue what binaries im using

Comment: @Hang If you dont mind would you please explain to me step by step how I would go about that? PATH isent a term im familier with

Comment: I think [this post] answers(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287379/how-do-i-add-to-the-windows-path-variable-using-setx-having-weird-problems) the PATH part.

Comment: Removing rails and ruby-on-rails tags, since this problem has nothing to do with any language or framework. @NerretRAISE, you should use your search engine to learn about paths and how they work -- you appear to be running into very fundamental issues that have basically nothing to do with programming. Stack Overflow isn't here for tutorial purposes, and questions of such nature are not typically well received.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I see, im sorry

Answer (score 3):

SQLite is an *embedded* database; it does not run as a separate server process, but is a library that is usually compiled directly into the application itself.

Running the `sqlite3` command-line shell does not make sense, because the version of the SQLite library compiled into that is not necessarily related to the version compiled into the Ruby gem. The guide you linked to is wrong; just ignore that point.
(But if you want to test SQL queries outside of Ruby, there's nothing wrong with installing and running `sqlite3.exe`.)

You do not need to install the DLL manually; any program that needed it would already ship with it.

For how to test the SQLite Ruby gem, see the [sqlite3-ruby documentation](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby).

Answer (score -1):

[Guide of what a path is and how to add stuff to it it](http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/). You may also want to consider using [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/) as many members of the community prefer it over the packaged sqlite3.

These guys are also right about Ruby development kind of sucking on non-Unix systems though so if you plan on getting into this you might want to consider [dual booting a Linux OS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_FuLXIKLVjg) for development. You'll probably save yourself a lot of bugs.