# WinError 2 for openbte pip program

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

I recently got a pip package called openbte (https://pypi.org/project/openbte/) to install on PyCharm after a lot of troubleshooting. However, when I try to run a command it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\openbte-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('openbte==0.9.24', 'console_scripts', 'openbte')()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\__main__.py", line 47, in main
    Geometry(**vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 83, in __init__
    data = self.compute_mesh_data()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 91, in compute_mesh_data
    self.import_mesh()
  File "C:\Users\turtl\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\openbte\geometry.py", line 448, in import_mesh
    a=subprocess.check_output(['gmsh','-' + str(self.dim),'mesh.geo','-o','mesh.msh'])
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 336, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\turtl\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong? I can find similar questions with this error, but they seem specific to the program. Line 997 seems to just be the startupinfo line of the following code.

```
    try:
        hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                 # no special security
                                 None, None,
                                 int(not close_fds),
                                 creationflags,
                                 env,
                                 os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
                                 startupinfo)
```

Comment: you have to print `executable` to find out. Looks like you're trying to start `gmsh` and it's not in the path. Maybe you have to install it ? (http://gmsh.info/)

Comment: I've downloaded gmsh. Do you know how I would go about putting it in the path?

Comment: I think you can google that. Some links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287379/how-do-i-add-to-the-windows-path-variable-using-setx-having-weird-problems