# How to set an environment variable dependent on another one? (Windows)

Tags: windows, environment-variables, windows-console

I am looking for a way on Windows how to set an environment variable dependent on another one. In my case, I want to add the new path to `PYTHONPATH`. Let's say, that there is an existing environment variable

```
%INSTALLATION_DIR% = D:\Programs\MyProject
```

The easiest way to do that would be:

```
SETX PYTHONPATH "%PYTHONPATH%;%INSTALLATION_DIR%\Utility\Scripts"
```

But then, `%INSTALLATION_DIR%` is directly replaced by `D:\Programs\MyProject`, so `PYTHONPATH` is not updated if `%INSTALLATION_DIR%` changes.

Is there a way to write the text `%INSTALLATION_DIR%` into an environment variable, without evaluating the variable directly?

If possible, I want to do that in an automated way (so using the console, powershell or python), as a want to write a script which adds a list of paths to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: guess you are looking for delayedexpansion. kindly refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file

Comment: Thank you for the link, but this is not that I'm looking for. The problem is not that the variables can change during the script, but that I want to use the text '%INSTALLATION_DIR%' instead of the value of this environment variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the solution. If the name of the environment variable is written in quotes, it will not be evaluated.

`SETX PYTHONPATH "%PYTHONPATH%;%"INSTALLATION_DIR"%\Utility\Scripts"`

Comment: Note that `INSTALLATION_DIR` should be a simple value that doesn't depend on other environment variables. In the registry it should be a `REG_SZ`, while `PYTHONPATH` will be a `REG_EXPAND_SZ`. Windows takes care to load all `REG_SZ` values before `REG_EXPAND_SZ` values, so it's always okay for the latter to depend on the former.

Comment: Note also that using setx.exe by itself expands the current `PYTHONPATH` value, which may depend on other variables. To prevent this you need to get the unexpanded value via reg.exe.

Comment: Also, it's documented by example in the help that setx.exe will replace "~" with "%" to get around shell expansion.

Comment: Thank you for your hints. The variants using "~" or "^%" instead of "%" only work if the new environment variable only contains a single path. As PYTHONPATH contains multiple, I solved it by reading in PYTHONPATH using os.environ[PYTHONPATH] (in python) and replacing all % characters by %" or "%.

Comment: If you're using Python, you should use the winreg module to read and modify the unexpanded value. For example: `k = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 'Environment');` `new_value = winreg.QueryValueEx(k, 'PYTHONPATH')[0] + r';%INSTALLATION_DIR%\Utility\Scripts'`. setx.exe notifies Explorer to update its environment, so you probably want to use it to set the value instead of winreg. For example: `subprocess.call('setx.exe PYTHONPATH "{}"'.format(new_value))`. Note there's no CMD shell involved in this case, so you don't have to worry about escaping percents in the command line.

Comment: Retrieving the unexpanded value can be done directly in bat/cmd as well, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566845/2144408).

Answer (score 0):

treat the % as you would treat a special character. double the `%`
so

`SETX PYTHONPATH "%PYTHONPATH%;%%INSTALLATION_DIR%%\Utility\Scripts"`

Comment: This results in %D:\Programs\MyProject%\Utility\Scripts

Comment: This answer should go into a bat file, and then be run. You pasted it directly into a CMD window, in which case you need to escape % with ^. Isn't CMD a wonderful programming language?