# How can we add path for pycharm in the environment variables

Tags: python, cmd, path, pycharm, pythonpath

When I type in cmd like this:

```
G:\python-project\first>pycharm64.
```

I get the following output:

> Pycharm is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: Are you trying to open pycharm from the command prompt/powershell? If so you'll have to add your installation directory to path environment variable. Using default option add `C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm xyz\bin` to path where xyz is dependent on version installed.
For how to add to path see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287379/how-do-i-add-to-the-windows-path-variable-using-setx-having-weird-problems/26947177) for using it from terminal or google it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find the "bin" folder under your Pycharm installation location and put that in the Path environment variable.

To find the bin folder location:

1. Open Windows start menu and start typing PyCharm
2. Right click on the icon go to "More > Open File Location"
3. Right click in the location on the Pycharm icon and Select "Properties"
4. Select "Open File Location Button"
5. Copy This Path

To edit the path variable

1. Open Windows start menu and start typing "environment variables"
2. Select "Edit the System Environment Variables"
3. On the popup click on the button "Environment Variables..."
4. Under the System Variables section find the Path Variable
5. Click the button "Edit"
6. Add a **New** entry with a value of the copied Path
7. Save settings and close all windows

Open a **NEW** terminal and you can enter your command

Note: Steps might be slightly different depending on your version of the Windows OS