# How to execute a command in already open CMD window using VBScirpt

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I am trying to automate backups that have to be done daily. I have a program running in CMD, which needs to be properly closed before running the backup.
The two commands that it needs to close are:
shutdown
yes (to acknowledge the action)

Then that CMD window can be closed, and I already have .bat file written to execute a backup.

I have never written VBScripts except very very simple ones, so I am sorry if my question is not clear enough.

The idea is this - using VBScript, type in both shutdown {Enter} and yes {Enter}, then close that CMD window, and then execute backup batch file, which already is set to start the CMD program once it is done backing up.

Operating System - Windows XP Professional

Thank you!

Comment: Google windows automation. Your first problem will be finding the cmd window.Is this program running in this window yours? Might be a lot easier to signal it to close itself

Comment: Are you starting that "program running in CMD" specifically to prepare the files intended for the backup? Is that a console program? Is there any other interaction during the process other than entering "shutdown" and "yes"? Depending on the answers to those questions, piping the input might work.

Comment: @AndriyM - Thank you for looking into this matter. Unfortunately I am not familiar at all with console or piping, but program that is running within CMD window - monitoring program of database, it receives data from multiple clients and logs it in database, and retrieves data when asked by clients. Those two commands are the only ones needed to shutdown this monitoring program and thus avoid corruption of the database before backing it up. So if the piping method is still a solution - what is it, and how do I use it? Thank you again!

Comment: I may have been too hasty, that piping method may not be a good idea for your situation, after all. If it is an interactive program that is supposed to accept other commands too during its execution, then you are indeed going to need something else.

Answer (score 3):

You could try typing in the commands programmatically by sending keystrokes as Windows messages to the CMD window where your program is running.

I don't know VBS, perhaps it has a function or functions mapping to the system API functions [`PostMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [`SendMessage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Would be great if it did, especially if someone posted an answer explaining how to use them. In the meantime, I can show you how to use this method with the help of a *utility* called [SendMessage](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/SendMessage.html), in a batch file.

Basically, the utility allows you to send an arbitrary Windows message to an arbitrary window like this:

```
SendMessage.exe target_specification /message:value /wparam:value /lparam:value
```

I'll be addressing the *`target_specification`* bit a bit later, and the other parameters are:

- `/message:value` – the message being sent, specified by *`code`*. In you case it would be either of these:

  ```
  /message:WM_CHAR
  /message:258
  /message:0x0102
  ```

  which all specify the [WM_CHAR message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- `/wparam:value` – for the WM_CHAR message, this one should be the code of the keystroke being sent.

  In your case, since your commands consist of ASCII characters only, all the codes would match the ASCII codes of the corresponding characters. Therefore, you can use an [ASCII chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) to convert the characters in your commands. The `s`, for instance would be

  ```
  /wparam:115
  ```

  and `h`

  ```
  /wparam:104
  ```

  and so on.

  Note that you will also need to be sending the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key presses too. According to the [ASCII control code chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_code_chart), it would be

  ```
  /wparam:13
  ```
- `/lparam:value` – you can see from the [WM_CHAR's manual page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646276%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the LPARAM parameter is actually supposed to carry multiple pieces of information as a single numeric value. However, for your specific case it would be enough to just memorise that this parameter should be specified simply as

  ```
  /lparam:1
  ```

Now to the target specification part. This one may be tricky. You will learn from the description at [the tool's web page](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/SendMessage.html) that there are different ways of specifying the target window. Not every method may work for you, though.

For instance, you could try specifying the target by the process name:

```
/processname:name_of_your_executable
```

However, if you are not invoking your program directly and instead are calling it in e.g. a batch file, then the program will not be running in its own window but will rather be borrowing the hosting CMD session's window, and so this method will likely not work.

If that is indeed how you invoke the program, then you could try using the window title to specify the target:

```
/windowtitle:window_title
```

The only caveat to keep in mind here is that the title must uniquely identify the required window, or the keystrokes would be sent to all the windows matching the specified title. You could try uniquifying the title by using the `title` command in the batch that calls the program (setting it prior to calling the program).

So, to sum it up, here's how the complete backup script (*batch* script) might look like, assuming, for the purpose of the example, that the target window will be specified by its title:

```
@ECHO OFF
:: s
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:115 /lparam:1
:: h
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:104 /lparam:1
:: u
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:117 /lparam:1
:: t
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:116 /lparam:1
:: d
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:100 /lparam:1
:: o
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:111 /lparam:1
:: w
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:119 /lparam:1
:: n
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:110 /lparam:1
:: ENTER
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:13 /lparam:1

:: y
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:121 /lparam:1
:: e
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:101 /lparam:1
:: s
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:115 /lparam:1
:: ENTER
SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:13 /lparam:1

:: wait for some time (~3 sec) till the program shuts down, if necessary
PING -n 4 localhost 1>NUL

:: proceed with the back-up
...
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much! I can see that I am very close now to getting this done! I did everything you told me above, learned a lot about WM_CHAR. Now, for some reason when I use in .bat command SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:115 /lparam:1, it does not type any letters in a window at all. But if I type SendMessage.exe /windowtitle:"My Title" /message:16 - I get a message that warns me that I am about to force close the window.

Comment: From that I concluded that locating of the window is not a problem - it finds it well, but looks like I am doing something wrong when using WM_CHAR command. From looking at WM_CHAR in Microsoft website, I read something about it using UTF-16 character encoding, so that made me think maybe I should use some different numbers to represent letters?

Comment: Sorry, didn't have the chance to see your response last night. Not much to tell here at this point, though. I did my tests under Windows 7 x64. I tried `SendMessage` on a "clean" `cmd.exe` session (i.e. I just ran `cmd.exe`, set the title, then sent WM_CHARs) and on a CMD session with an `ftp.exe` in it (`cmd.exe`, set the title, `ftp.exe` from it, which initiated its own session inside the same window, then I sent WM_CHARs). Both tests were successful. I don't know, maybe you're using a DOS (*actual* DOS) program and it can't receive any WM_CHARs. Can't verify that under my Win 7, I'm afraid.

Comment: There *is* one idea, though, and one, too, that I myself was prepared to use when I first started using SendMessage for my own purposes. (Like you, I use it for sending WM_CHARs. They work well for me most likely because the target in my case is a GUI program.) You could try replacing every single WM_CHAR with two messages, [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646281%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), sent in that order. (Yes, that's more reading up for you, sorry about that.)

Comment: I'm going to try this method myself, for my own education as well as to be able to try and come up with an alternative script for you, just can't promise that it will happen very soon.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! Yes, it is DOS program, and in TaskMgr I have ntvdm.exe running when my DOS program is running. I noticed on the net there are several posts about using virtual input for DOS pgms, but those posts are above my head. They talking about C++, which I never did anything with, and from what I gathered there is no use of Keybd_event in a batch file. Keybd_event is something that I understood CAN do the trick. Then there is a VBS file that can accomplish the task of sending keys to any DOS program - its a dark forest for me! - http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19094

Comment: After looking at the code in the above link I started to understand that it is something else - VB instead of VBS, which I do not know if useful. Then there is another post I found, but I cannot understand what these two were talking about (VBS, BATCH or still same strange VB). - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/rB3mwq4C3oQ

Comment: Unable to workout the right way of using WM_KEYDOWN & WM_KEYUP so far. Some evidence I've found over the Internet suggests that using those directly to emulate keystrokes may actually be very hard. Anyway, I have discovered such a thing as [`SendKeys`](http://www.pctools.com/guides/scripting/detail/149/?act=reference) in VBS (not the one you've found, I haven't actually had the chance of taking a proper look at it). Seems to work smooth for me but again, I cannot test it with a real DOS program.