# Send Command to CMD.exe using Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-server-2012

Hi I'm trying to send the command "shutdown" to an already open command prompt called Administrator:  Transaction Server using a BAT file but when i run the BAT file nothing happens.

I followed this question - [How to execute a command in already open CMD window using VBScirpt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20640057/how-to-execute-a-command-in-already-open-cmd-window-using-vbscirpt)

Does anyone know why?

Here's my code:

```
:: s
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:115 /lparam:1
:: h
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:104 /lparam:1
:: u
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:117 /lparam:1
:: t
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:116 /lparam:1
:: d
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:100 /lparam:1
:: o
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:111 /lparam:1
:: w
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:119 /lparam:1
:: n
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:110 /lparam:1
:: ENTER
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:13 /lparam:1

:: ENTER
SendMessage-1.1.2.exe /windowtitle:"Test Server" /message:WM_CHAR /wparam:13 /lparam:1

:: wait for some time (~3 sec) till the program shuts down, if necessary
PING -n 4 localhost 1>NUL

pause
...
```

Comment: I don't mean to be a pain here. It's just that with questions, they should remain just that, questions. What works for you might be slightly different for others so they can add answers. In this case only one answer but not always the case. Please refrain from adding "answer" text into the question. It helps to avoid confusion. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which sendmessage you are using. I downloaded this
[SendMessage.exe: Access to advanced Windows features](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7583) from Dostips.com author:aacini

And with this batch I managed to run shutdown in another cmd window titled `Test-Msg`:

```
@ECHO OFF

Set /A WM_CHAR=0x0102
Set Msg=%WM_CHAR%

Set Win="Test-Msg"
::          s   h   u   t   d   o   w   n   ret
For %%A in (115 104 117 116 100 111 119 110 13) Do (
echo SendMessage.exe %Win% %Msg% %%A 1
     SendMessage.exe %Win% %Msg% %%A 1
)
Pause
SendMessage.exe %Win% %Msg% 13 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. If i wanted to enter another return after the message "press any key to continue" is displayed in the CMD how would i do this? @LotPings

Comment: See above changed batch.

Comment: With the above code the Test-Msg cmd window is staying open C:/Desktop is there a way to close the Test-Msg window? @LotPings

Comment: @user1798578 Do another loop and send exit[ret]
`For %%A in (101 120 105 116 13) do ....`