# gulp command not found - error after installing gulp

Tags: windows, node.js, gulp

I've installed Gulp both globally and locally using

```
npm install gulp
npm install gulp -g
npm install gulp-util
npm install gulp-util -g
```

When try to run gulp I get

`'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`

Running npm list gulp (or -g), I `gulp@3.7.0` with the location of either my global or local gulp installation.

I've tried running `node gulpfile.js` pointed to my gulp file, and it runs without error, and of course, it starts with `require('gulp')`.

Any suggestions on getting Gulp working on Windows(8.1)?

Comment: I'm not using gulp on windows, but have you tried `npm install gulp --save-dev` ?

Comment: @soenguy that will not solve it

Comment: @pedalpete did my answer solve your question? Please mark it if so

Comment: I was having this issue until I removed node.js COMPLETELY and reinstalled/restarted my computer. I was getting all sorts of weird errors from my node plugins.

Comment: I encountered this problem recently: turns out the only thing that I forgot was to add the folder where the executable `gulp` program lies to the Windows %PATH% variable. In my case: `%AppData%\Roaming\npm`

Comment: This will solve the problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/45707907/5222115

Comment: If you're on Windows and gulp is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file try running gulp.js instead.

I'm working on a laravel project, and running gulp locally. Also use something other then Windows command prompt, because you will probably get an error with gulp.js. I am using Git bash, and it works perfectly.

Comment: On my side, it was a "permission to run script" that was not enabled on my computer. Source : http://www.octetmalin.net/windows/scripts/powershell-activer-execution-des-scripts.php (french) 

Had to run ` set-executionpolicy unrestricted ` in the powershell in admin mode to fix the issue.

Comment: Dropping an additional comment here for Windows users. After all these suggestions, if you're using Git Bash, try PowerShell instead. For some reason Git Bash refuses to work while PowerShell does.

Answer (score 270):

You forgot to install the gulp-cli package:

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

Then you can run the command "gulp" from the command line.

Comment: Yeah, after the registery change didn't work this did the trick : ' )

Comment: This piece wasn't even included in our artifactory to grab, so couldn't get it to install it.

Comment: This fixed the problem for the "Learn Bootstrap 4 Final in 2018 with our Free Crash Course" tutorial. I will put a link to this answer in that guys tutorial for others who might have the same problem

Comment: Not good solution for my case. I am using azure pipelines with self hosted agent. I don't want to install the gulp globally because different projects may require different versions of gulp. What options do I have? Please help

Comment: It's tough coming back to legacy projects like this where you can't remember how they work. Thanks, saved me some time.

Answer (score 230):

The issue and answer can be found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/1041104

The npm modules such as gulp are not installed to the path. Thus are not found when you run them in the CMD.

If gulp has been installed globally, you can use the process below:

1. Create an environmental variable called `NODE_PATH`
2. Set it to: `%AppData%\npm\node_modules` or `%AppData%\npm` on windows 8-10
3. Close CMD, and Re-Open to get the new ENV variables

[image: Add Node path to environmental variables]

Running `npm ls` and `npm ls -g` shows that they are installed, but the CMD can not find them due to `the missing link`.

Comment: I think that it's important to note, however, that the answer provided DOES NOT WORK if gulp has not been installed globally. the %AppData%\npm folder is completely empty on initial installation and if you only install gulp in a project folder without using -g, it doesn't put the batch file in \npm\ or its files in \npm\node_modules . So in reality BOTH answers here are necessary.

Comment: I tried this and it still didn't work for me until I realised my "Path" environment variable name was in camel case and not "PATH" (in upper case). I modified "Path" to "PATH" and added my npm directory to the beginning as in @CIAODO 's answer. For some reason "%AppData%\Roaming\npm didn't work for me so I had to use the full path: "C:\Users\\[user.name]\AppData\Roaming\npm;". Combined with this answer it worked for me.

Comment: %AppData%\Roaming\npm didn't work for me too, also had to use the full path: "C:\Users\[user.name]\AppData\Roaming\npm;"

Comment: adding %AppData%\npm to PATH worked for me (Windows 10)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work but after I restarted my pc, it worked. Don't know what happened.

Comment: @outofBounds that worked for me as well on win10, whereas the other steps did not. gulp had been working fine for me until today, not sure what changed.

Comment: If you're using the terminal Git Bash, it's not aware of %AppData%\Roaming\npm but instead I added this to ~/.bash_profile: export PATH=$PATH:/c/Users/MyUsername/AppData/Roaming/npm and it found gulp after doing: source ~/.bash_profile

Comment: @phpguru you are telling me that windows now supports only half of bash? lol! Thanks for commenting, if others have the same issue I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: Can use the [`setx`](https://superuser.com/a/79614/292784) command to achieve it; `setx NODE_PATH %AppData%\npm` (Windows 10). And I realized I didn't have the necessary packages installed globally, so be sure to use the `npm install -g <package_name>` to populate the `node_modules` folder in the `NODE_PATH`

Comment: I am using azure pipelines with self hosted agent. I don't want to install the `gulp` globally what options do I have? Please help.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar Use the node_modules installed bin file: `./node_modules/.bin/gulp`

Answer (score 92):

1. Be sure that you have gulp and `gulp.cmd` *(use windows search)*
2. Copy the path of `gulp.cmd` *(`C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Roaming\npm`)*
3. Add this path to the Path envirement variable **or** edit `PATH` environment variable and add `%APPDATA%\npm`
4. Reopen cmd.

Add `%APPDATA%\npm` to front of Path, not end of the Path.

Comment: Add %APPDATA%\npm to front of Path, not end of the Path.

Comment: Thank you @CIAODO! my path had crap from an earlier node install for testing purposes and you comment helped me track it down.`:)

Comment: It just stopped working for me suddenly, I think after I changed some other PATH variables. Your first solution was the only one that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 48):

1. Install gulp globally.

   `npm install -g gulp`
2. Install gulp locally in the project.

   `npm install gulp`
3. Add below line in your package.json

   `"scripts": {
         "gulp": "gulp"
    }`
4. Run gulp.

   `npm run gulp`

This worked for me.

Comment: After doing Step 4, it did not run for me - it just returned back another command line prompt after doing nothing (visible, at least).  If I did just `gulp` after that, then it ran.

Comment: Brilliant. This was the solution to my failing build process that relied on Gulp in AppVeyor . Rather, I used something like `"package": "gulp build"`.

Comment: But its not a permanent solution, I need to revert these changes before pushing code, because on others contributor this changes makes builds failed due to conflict :(

Comment: This is not good solution. As I am using a self hosted agent in azure pipeline, I don't want to install the gulp globally as different projects may require different versions of gulp.

Answer (score 33):

I am using Windows 8.1. I had the same problem.

I installed gulp using Node.js command prompt

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Then go to the required directory in Node.js command prompt and try

```
gulp -v
```

If you get gulp local version not found exit the current Node.js command prompt and try the above command in a new Node.js command prompt

I tried the NODE_PATH mentioned by @SteveLacy but the command prompt was still not able to detect gulp command

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I think your answer is not solving (or trying to solve) the problem.

Comment: not working, OP mentioned that this has been tried. I ran into the same issue, tried it and it does not fix the issue.

Comment: Does it provide answer? Well, it solved my issue! thanks a lot

Comment: There isn't even an answer in this. This was the question in the first place.

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. Haters gonna hate.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me on my Windows Surface Book, when installing a local version of gulp. Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Had the same problem, not really best solution but install it globally:

```
npm install -g gulp
```

Of course it's best to still have it in `package.json`, so you can do the following to install it locally and add an entry into `package.json`:

```
npm install --save-dev gulp
```

Everything else (gulp plugins) install also locally.

Answer (score 20):

The simple solution just do `npm link gulp`

Comment: what is this doing under the hood?

Comment: Looks like a symbolic link

Answer (score 19):

I was having the same problem when trying to get gulp working on a co-workers VM.  It seems the problem stems from the users folder.

Adding NODE_PATH in my environment variables didn't fix the problem.

If you edit your 'Path' variable in your system variables and add '%APPDATA%\npm' at the end of that, it should fix the problem... Unless you or somebody else npm installed gulp as another user than the one you're currently logged in as.

If you want it to be available for all users, put 'C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\npm'(or where ever you have gulp) explicitly instead of using '%APPDATA%\npm'.  You can also move the files to a more user-indifferent path.

Don't forget to start a new cmd prompt, because the one you have open won't get the new 'Path' variable automatically.

Now 'gulp'.

Answer (score 17):

One right way:

1. Win + R : type "%appdata%"
2. Go to npm folder
3. Copy whole path like "C:\Users\...\npm"
4. Go to "My Computer" + Right Click "Properties"
5. Open "Advanced System Settings" (On the left)
6. Click on "Environment Variables"
7. Click on "Edit Path"
8. Add that "C:\Users\...\npm" to the end and type ";" after that
9. Click ok, reopen `cmd` and try `npm` command again

Comment: I think things are good explained here and it should be the first thing to try when you see `gulp' is not recognized` on windows

Comment: the main thing is to add `";"` at the end. otherwise it won't work

Comment: cmd+R, do u mean winkey+R

Answer (score 15):

You should first install `gulp` as global using:

```
npm install gulp -g
```

Otherwise the path solution will not resolve the problem.

Then add the npm modules path to the PATH using:

```
PATH = %PATH%;%APPDATA%\npm
```

Comment: Is the information you've added new and distinctly different from what the other 33 answers give?  My impression is 'No', in which case, you probably shouldn't have added the answer.

Comment: I've tried many of them without success and i've figured out the need to install gulp globaly so to avoid anyone else the same pain i've added this answer

Answer (score 14):

In my case it was that I had to install
gulp-cli by command `npm -g install gulp-cli`

Answer (score 9):

Try to add to your PATH variable the following:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

I had the same problem and I solved adding the path to my node modules.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem setting it up in windows 10. My answer is windows specific (look at the answers for modifying path in bash for a linux or OSX solution)

The core problem I had was that npm's folder was not registered in the path.
I originally tried changing this in cmd prompt.

```
setx path "%path%;%appdata$\npm"
```

Note that I used setx instead of set to ensure that the update to the environmental variable remains. Also note that it's a backslash.

This should work but for me it didn't because setx has a limit of only accepting 1024 characters... (yes it's nonsensical to me as well).

So try the above and if you get a warning like did about reaching the 1024 limit, then you can do the other way I ended up doing.

First while youre still in the console, type: `echo %appdata%\npm` ... this is your npm folder that you want to add to the path so add it to your clipboard.

You have to go into the registry and reach the following folder:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

Then append the 'Path' value with the npm folder path in your clipboard. Reboot to activate the new value and you should now be good to go.

[image: using regedit]

Finally, just test it all out

```
>npm install -g gulp
>gulp
```

Comment: Yes!!! Finally! I have looked all over for something to help. Almost all of the answers say to install it globally and it should work. I've installed, uninstalled, reinstalled, cleared cache, etc. At last, this worked. Thank you!

Comment: @Josh, glad I could get you running. Setting up an environment is a b*tch. I think I switched over to mac mostly because of these little quirks when using windows shell.

Comment: The worst part is that I've had it set up for months. It's been running fine. Then I'm programming one day and my commands aren't recognized. I search the Internet for anything that will help. Everyone says the same thing. Then you come along and BAM! It works. I understand why you would switch to OSX. I've never had these kind of quirks with OSX before. But I'm too committed to Windows.

Comment: well to your benefit, I believe windows 10 is adopting native bash shell. Should make life a LOT easier for some of these tools.

Comment: This work for me in Windows Server 2008, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

This ended up being a 'user' issue with me. I had installed npm and node on the system logged in as user1, then I set-up user2. I could run node, and I could run npm commnds, but could not run any npm packages from the command line.

I uninstalled node and npm, and reinstalled under the correct user in order to solve the problem. After that I can run packages from the command-line without issue.

Comment: The same for me, the other answers didn't work - reinstalling node and npm did the job

Answer (score 6):

The top answer did not work for me.

I am using a virtual machine that had a previous owner. The previous owner had an old version of npm installed. Using that, I was installed gulp globally with `npm install -g gulp`. Running the command `gulp` would return `'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. As I said, the top Answer did not fix my problem. I basically had to reinstall nodejs.

**Solution**

1. Re-download [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
2. `npm install -g gulp`
3. `gulp -version`

This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I recommend using nvm for switching node versions: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: @chrisyo8989 - awesome.. this worked for me without the environmental vars Thanks! I hate messing with those!

Comment: I reinstalled nodejs (repair mode) and after that gulp npm install -g gulp and without a restart it worked - YES. WIndows 10.

Answer (score 4):

I had v0.12.3 of Nodejs on Win7 x64 and ran into similar issues when I tried installing gulp. This worked for me:

1. Uninstalled Nodejs
2. Installed Nodejs v0.10.29
3. npm install -g npm
4. npm install -g gulp

Comment: I used just `npm install -g npm` and `npm install -g gulp` and things go back to normal

Comment: I recommend using nvm for switching node versions: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 4):

The NodeJS installer appears to add the user/AppData/Roaming/npm path to the user environment path, which is appropriate.

Normally, the PATH environment variable at the command line is the combination of the user environment path and the system environment path.

However, if the user environment path + the system environment path is larger than about 1920 characters, Windows does not not combine the user and system paths - only the system environment path is used.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21270921/301152

So, when you open the Advanced System Settings in Windows to edit your environment variables, take a look to see if the user/AppData/Roaming/npm path is already in your user environment PATH. If it is, then the problem is that your user + system paths are too long, causing Windows to ignore your user path.  Trim your user and/or system path strings and gulp should work as installed.

If you can't find anything to trim away from your user and system paths, then add the user/AppData/Roaming/npm path to the system environment path and call it a hack.

Comment: I have spent hours trying to get the gulp command working in windows, and this was what finally worked for me. So thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
 npm link gulp
 npm update
```

Comment: This was what fixed the issue for me on Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same problem after installation. So i tried running `cmd` with elevated privileges (admin) and it worked.

**Screen capture:**

[image: cmd]

Comment: Administrator mode in CMD did it for me

Comment: I tried everything else. But once I ran command prompt in administrator mode it worked for me.

Comment: Odd - should not require admin privileges.  This might work for some, but something else is wrong (not related to Gulp) if it requires this.

Answer (score 4):

Add this path in your Environment Variables PATH
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\

Answer (score 4):

(Windows 10) I didn't like the path answers. I use choco package manager for node.js. Gulp would not fire for me unless it was:

1. Globally installed `npm i -g gulp` **and local dir** `npm i --save-dev gulp`
2. The problem persisted beyond this once, which was fixed by **completely removing node.js and reinstalling it.**

I didn't see any comments about local/global **and** node.js removal/reinstall.

Answer (score 3):

This is most commonly because it is not found on environment variables as others have pointed out. This is what worked for me.

> echo %PATH%

This will show you what's one your PATH environment variable. If node_modules is not there there do the following to add it from your APPDATA path.

> PATH = %PATH%; %APPDATA%\npm

Comment: That's the only correct answer here. Either set a NODE_PATH variable AND add it to the PATH variable or directly add the global npm folder to your PATH variable.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it by adding
`C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\npm`
to `PATH`
and not
`C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

Comment: This solution was already posted in [December 2014](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27295145/1906307).

Answer (score 3):

I already had the one condition from this answer (I don't know why)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27295145/1175496

That is, my PATH already included `%APPDATA%\npm`

In my case, the problem was *npm was not installing modules there* (again, I don't know why)

Therefore I needed to do this:

`$ npm config set prefix -g %APPDATA%/npm`

After that, running 
`$ npm install -g gulp` (or installing any other module) put the module in the place where PATH expects it.

Answer (score 3):

In windows:

1. Using your windows explorer, Navigate to your vagrant shared folder (I am using scotchbox by the way) e.g `C:\scotchbox/public/gulpProject`
2. In the address bar of the folder, type `cmd` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Do your gulp installation `npm install`

Answer (score 3):

On my Windows 10 Enterprise, gulp was not installed in %AppData%, which is C:\Users\*username*\AppData\npm\node_modules on my machine, but in C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Local\npm\node_modules.

To get gulp to be picked up at the command prompt or in powershell, I added to the user PATH the value *C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm*.  After that it worked like a charm.  Naturally I had to close the command prompt or powershell window and re-open for the above to take effect.

Answer (score 2):

Had gulp command not found problem in windows 10 and Adding "%AppData%\npm\node_modules" doesn't work for me.
Do this steps please:

After doing

`npm install -g npm`

And

`npm install -g gulp`

Add

`C:\Users\YourUsername\npm`

to Path in System Variables.

It Works for me after all solutions failed me.

Answer (score 2):

Run `npm install gulp -g`

if you are using windows, please add the gulp's dir to PATH.

such like `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp`

Answer (score 2):

### In short:

You should add `%NODE_PATH%` to the system variable `Path` if the other answers don't work.

### The reason:

The point is, command prompt only executes programs under the **`Path` system variable**, not the **user variables**. If you have `NODE_PATH` set as a user variable, add `%NODE_PATH%` to `Path`.

---

I asked here and got marked duplicate for a question with different intention :(

[NPM Windows doesn't execute program under the User Variable path [duplicate]](https://superuser.com/questions/1029825/npm-windows-doesnt-execute-program-under-the-user-variable-path)

Answer (score 2):

In Windows:

1. Press the following two keys: **Windows** + **r**
2. Type `control /name microsoft.system` into the run dialog box that appears from the previous step.

[image: Windows run dialog box]

3. Select **Advanced System Settings** from the left of the window pane
4. Click the **Advanced** tab on the system properties box that appears and click the **Environment Variables** button.
5. **Edit** the `PATH` User environment variable.
6. Click **New** on the edit environment variable window that pops up for the `PATH` variable and add the following: `%APPDATA%\npm` to the start of the `PATH` environment variable (as shown in the image below).

[image: Setting the environmental variable]

7. Close your **Command Prompt** and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to where you installed node modules in cmd up to .bin folder, then run gulp.  I.e. path\node_modules.bin>>gulp
This worked for me excellently. My path was C:\wamp\www\wyntonv2\node_modules.bin

Answer (score 1):

If you need to install a global version gulp as described on the [gulpjs.com](http://gulpjs.com/) site and still have issues, you may need to clean npm's cache. For instance, if you have previously installed gulp and managed to blow it away by accident, it may not install properly again because it's looking for directories that no longer exist. In which case, run:

sudo npm cache clean

Then install gulp as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, none of the approaches listed worked. I finally downloaded Rapid Environment Editor (ver 8).

It showed that my additions to the user environment variables weren't present. When I added them with REE, everything worked immediately.

(Running Windows 8.1)

Answer (score 1):

I have come across this issue. I fixed this by adding %APPDATA%/npm to Path Environment variable. I didn't define NODE_PATH variable still it worked for me. Hope this works for others!!

Answer (score 0):

1. When you've installed gulp global, you need to go to

   C:\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npm
2. There you do

   SHIFT + Right Click
3. Choose "Open command prompt here"
4. Run gulp from that cmd window

Answer (score 0):

Nothing Worked for me except

Run powershell as administrator and executing `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`.

For More Detail : [PowerShell says "execution of scripts is disabled on this system."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-says-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system)

Answer (score 0):

Run Power-shell as administrator.

then run this command

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

**Use with CAUTION**

Answer (score 0):

Above solution are awesome, but here I want to share an solution for Existing Project in which this issue got reported many times due to which we use to reinstall Gulp and all.

**Environment for Issue:-**

- Current OS:- Windows 10 x64 bit.
- Working with Gulp Project with previous version of Node v10.24.0 and now not working with Node v14.15.0.

**Solution:-**

- First Option:- Changed in Node Version of the Project Directory from v14.15.0 to v10.24.0 and than Gulp Command runs fine.
- Second Option:-. Reinstall all the Packages and Gulp with Current Version of Node v14.15.0.

Hope this would be helpful to anyone.

Answer (score -1):

So I haven't seen this answer yet, and that `NODE_PATH` and all these other so-called environment variable fixes didn't do anything, so I thought I'd add my brute force way of getting this to work:

Obviously you install the latest `node.js` and do `npm install`.  I also had to upgrade some dependencies first (was getting warnings on these when I tried to install gulp, and before I ran these commands it was telling me it was missing the `popper.js` dependency Bootstrap 4 required - even though it was actually ok in that department!):

`npm install -g minimatch` (Enter)

`npm install -g graceful-fs` (Enter)

I saw when I did `npm install -g gulp`, again, though (and it was failing to run), it was putting it in 
**C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules**

So because I was running `gulp`  from a command line that was `cd`'d to my project folder in: 
**C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myproject**

I doubt it knew anything about that other location.  Also my package.json didn't have:

```
"scripts":{
    "gulp": "gulp"
 }
```

Instead, it had:

```
"scripts":{
    "start": "gulp"
 }
```

So it could not run `gulp`, anyway, even if it had been installed to the project. I guess at this point maybe if I had ran `start` instead of `gulp`, it might've worked, but so I added a comma after `"gulp"` and another line:

```
"scripts":{
    "start": "gulp",
    "gulp": "gulp"
 }
```

Then I copied the `gulp` folder from 
**C:\Users\myname\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp**
to
**C:\Users\myname\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\myproject\node_modules\gulp**

and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score -1):

None of the given answers didn't worked for me. Because my issue was the gulp commands are blocked by Antivirus. I had installed the Gulp both globally and locally successfully. Mine is Kaspersky antivirus and once i allowed gulp in the antivirus firewall it works like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

1. npm install -g gulp
2. Add environment variables in windows:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPyq2.png)