# node command line module commands are not working Windows 8

Tags: node.js

So  I'm having a lot of trouble getting my node module command line  commands to run correctly.

For example  if I  try and run  gulp   I get a

```
>gulp
'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So I have tried making my environment variable   NODE_PATH

%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\

%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules

%APPDATA%\npm

but none of these seem to work.   The only command I can use to get my  gulp to run  with    is

```
C:\Users\Aaron\Documents\GitHub\2015fallTeam14>node %NODE_PATH%gulp\bin\gulp
[12:10:32] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\GitHub\2015fallTeam14\gulpfile.js
```

It would appear that cmd is not running my node  with my NODE_PATH variable along with my command, but I do not know how to to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the system `PATH` variable to tell the command prompt where to find `gulp.bat` (which npm creates).

This has nothing to do with Node itself.

Comment: there is no  gulp.bat file.    Its a node module and is written in  javascript.

Comment: @McFrank: Wrong.  When you install an executable node module, npm will create a `.bat` (or `.cmd`; I forget which) in AppData that runs the node script.  This is the only reason it's possible to run on the command line.

Comment: ahh you are right its right there in the %AppData%/npm  directory  which is why it can run these command.


its the .cmd      That explains why editing the PATH variable works as it does ,  but I'm still left wondering why its not using my NODE_PATH  System Variable.

Comment: This is really strange.  I manage to get it working but on a restart

Comment: This is really strange. I manage to get the commands working but on a restart, they no longer work.    I had to move the %AppData%\npm  to the  start of the path environment variable  to get it working again

Comment: Looking at my set command it appears that %APPDATA% variable is not getting filled on restart.  Strangely enough  the APPDATA is set correctly but  inside of my path variable   it still appears as %APPDATA%.   Im going to try and figure out why this is happening.

For it to get filled out correctly I have to open my System Variables,  Edit the Path Variable , Save it and then close the menus.     On every restart

Comment: looks like  this may be the  fix for the issue I am having 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2913826

saldy the update has already been applied to my windows 8.1 machine .  Guess its time to get in contact with microsoft.

Comment: As a workaround, you could insert the actual path to the `AppData` folder (which will never change) directly.  Make sure to do that in the user PATH variable, not the system one.

Answer (score 0):

I had add the following

Edit "PATH" environment variable and add %APPDATA%\npm

from 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27295145/4249440

Im not sure why this works though.  I would like to know how the cmd knows to run  node  on this file path.