# Cannot install and run gulp via npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I am trying to install **gulp** via **npm** so that I can run my project.

As far as I can tell, all I need to do is run **"npm install gulp"** from the command line of my project location like so :

[image]

However it doesn't seem to work, because if I run "gulp" from the command line nothing happens.

[image]

In my package.json file I have these dependencies :

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-stylus": "^0.7.1",
    "browser-sync": "^2.8.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-minify-html": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-nunjucks-html": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.1",
    "gulp-stylus": "^2.0.6",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "jeet": "^6.1.2",
    "kouto-swiss": "^0.11.13",
    "minimist": "^1.1.3",
    "rupture": "^0.6.1"
  },
```

Is there some kind of conflict happening with my package.json file?

If I run "npm install grunt" from an empty directory I get this :

[image]

Sorry, I'm very new to npm, grunt, gulp etc.. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install `gulp` globally too:

```
npm -g install gulp
```

Comment: Damn. This caught me out again ;)

Comment: Gulp still a thing? :D

Comment: Grunt perhaps ?

Answer (score 3):

Install globally and make sure it is in your path. here is more info -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/24042936/173234

Answer (score 3):

This is a combo of understanding `npm` and `PATH` settings.  When you run `npm install gulp`, or `npm install` in general, it installs that module inside of the current directory under the node modules directory.  So if you are in `C:\Oliver\test` and you run `npm install gulp`, it will install gulp in `C:\Oliver\test\node_modules\gulp`.  Since the `PATH` variable, which is a variable that contains a list of directories to look up executables (like gulp), doesn't specify the `C:\Oliver\test\node_modules\gulp` directory, it will never find the gulp command.  To solve this, you need to use the `npm install -g` command where the `-g` flag specifies a global install, which means it puts it somewhere that is available in the `PATH` (I'm not sure where this is on Windows).