# The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet error

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, gulp

So I am trying to run gulp on our build server but keep getting the error above. Everything works fine if I log into the build server with my user account as I installed gulp globally under my account however when Jenkins runs my powershell script it fails with the error:

> The term 'gulp' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet error

So I tried to install globally in my script so that it installs with whatever user Jenkins uses.

Then I added `npm -g ls` to The powershell script and found that it is installed globally under a system user:

> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm >
>   gulp@3.9.0

Since I am still getting the error I took the advice from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp) and added a path variable with the directory above however still the same error.

Anyone have ideas on what I can try next? Im stumped as to why it is not working.

Comment: Which user account is Jenkins using? Can you log into this account and try to run gulp from the command line?

Comment: it is using a system user. I cannot login with that user.

Comment: In that case, can you run Jenkins as your user account and see if it will go through?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the directory containing `gulp.exe` is contained in the `$env:PATH` environment variable. You can update the *machine*-wide PATH variable with the  `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` method.

Let's imagine the path to the gulp executable is C:\Program Files\gulp\bin\gulp.exe

```
# Directory containing exe
$GulpFolderPath = 'C:\program files\gulp\bin'

# Retrieve user-agnostic PATH environment variable value
$CurrentEnvPath = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH','Machine')

# Check if PATH already contains gulp
if($CurrentEnvPath -split ';' -notcontains $GulpFolderPath)
{
    # if not, update it
    $NewEnvPath = $CurrentEnvPath,$GulpFolderPath -join ';'
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH',$NewEnvPath,'Machine')
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still not working. I will try and add some Write-Host statements to see "if PATH already contains gulp" is ever entered. Aslo Since it is gulp it is not an .exe file. I am specifying the path to the .cmd file. Not sure if that is correct.

Comment: `.cmd` vs `.exe` won't make a difference

Comment: I have the same issue... did you fix this?

Answer (score 0):

**Finally a true GULP solution**

After having searched for a solution the past two days without success, a colleague assisted me by running the following commands, the first installs gulp locally and globally and the second which I attribute the success for gulp finally running, installs the angular cli globally:

```
npm i -g gulp gulp
npm i @angular/cli -g
```

Afterwards I ran this command to update npm packages globally and locally; gulp finally worked:

```
npm install -g npm
```

Now running `gulp -v` yields success:

```
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2
```

NB: My OS is Windows 10 64 bit architecture latest updates on the 17th of July 2019. No proxy settings, no network ristrictions!!

If you do have a proxy before the internet configure your .npmrc file found by running the command `npm config edit` from your command line application:

```
proxy=x.x.x.x:PORT/
https-proxy=x.x.x.x:PORT/

prefix=C:\npm\node_modules
cache=C:\npm\cache
```