# Gulp global install doesn't work on Windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7, npm, gulp, installation

I am trying to install Gulp globally on a Windows 7 PC. In a command prompt I ran `npm install gulp -g`and it ran without any errors, although it did return the following warnings:

npm WARN install Couldn't install optional dependency: Failed to parse json
npm WARN install No data, empty input at 1:1
npm WARN install
npm WARN install ^

When I try to run gulp it says it is not recognized as an internal command.

If I check the `%AppData%/npm` directory, gulp.cmd is not there. Looking at all the answers to [gulp command not found - error after installing gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp), I take it this is where it should be.

Any ideas what has gone wrong, or where I can look to see what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to do a local install of gulp: `npm install gulp`, it actually showed an error:

> Failed to Parse json... File:
>   C:\Users\username|AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\clone\1.0.2\package\package.json

When I deleted this file and retried the Global install, it then worked.