# TFS MSBuild - Error : 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: tfs, msbuild, gulp

In building a **ASP.NET 5** Website; I'm Having trouble completing my Build using: Team Foundation Server Express 2015, 14.0.23128.0 (Tfs2015).  I followed these instructions "[Build and Deploy your ASP.NET 5 Application to an Azure Web App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5)" and my first problem was:

MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
[image]

..but I fixed it reading this "[MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp)".  However as I re-ran the build I now get this error:

```
##[error](152,5): Error : 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.DNX.Publishing.targets(152,5): error : 'gulp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, [C:\TfsData\Build\_work\6335c966\xxxx xxxxxx xxxx\<name>\src\<name>\<ProjectName>.xproj]
```

[image]

Now my question is since this error came using TFS MSBuild; is this a separate installation I have to perform in order for to complete this portion of the build as I've read here "[gulp command not found - error after installing gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp)"?

**EDIT:**

> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:\TfsData\Build_work\6335c966\xxxx xxxxxxx xxxx\XxxxXxxxxxxXxxx\src\XxxxXxxxxxxXxxx\XxxxXxxxxxxXxxx.xproj"
>
> (Build;FileSystemPublish target) (1) ->
>
> (GatherAllFilesToPublish target) ->
>
> DNU : error : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
>
> [C:\TfsData\Build_work\6335c966\xxxx xxxxxxx xxxx\XxxxXxxxxxxXxxx\src\XxxxXxxxxxxXxxx\XxxxXxxxxxxXxxx.xproj]

So does this mean shorter project path now? :/

**EDIT:**

I was hoping that would be the end of my worries, but after re-running a full build I now get errors in the PowerShell Script:

**Build Definition:**
[image]

**Build Failure:**
[image]

**Error Messages:**

```
2016-04-30T01:09:30.9536533Z Feeds used:
2016-04-30T01:09:30.9692820Z     https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6708908Z ##[error]Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6708908Z ##[error]260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]At C:\TfsData\Build\_work\2b986420\<name>\RDPlus\Prebuild.ps1:24 char:1
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]+ Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ...
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\TfsData\Buil...es\spdx-correct:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongExcept 
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]   ion
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error] 
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]At C:\TfsData\Build\_work\2b986420\<name>\RDPlus\Prebuild.ps1:24 char:1
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]+ Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ...
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]    + CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (C:\TfsData\Buil...se\node_modules:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongExcept 
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]   ion
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
2016-04-30T01:09:31.6865190Z ##[error]
..... lots more of the same..
```

These error are coming from the Prebuild.ps1 in the instructions in "[Build and Deploy your ASP.NET 5 Application to an Azure Web App](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/azure/deploy-aspnet5)"

```
# run DNU restore on all project.json files in the src folder including 2>1 to redirect stderr to stdout for badly behaved tools
Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot\src -Filter project.json -Recurse | ForEach-Object { & dnu restore $_.FullName 2>1 }
```

Thanks for your help!...

Comment: Yes you need to install Gulp and add it to the PATH environment variable. Then restart the build agent.

Comment: Thanks jessehouwing, that it the job, I appreciate your help!  But now its complaining about my path length,  see edit above.

Comment: That's a common problem with node and gulp. It will require more creative mapping of your workspaces (only map the folders you really need to the workspace root) and/or moving the build folder to a higher directory, say `e:\w`.