# nodejs: can not run gulp with local system account

Tags: node.js, gulp, teamcity

I have gulp installed in both locally and globally. I can run gulp in normal command line, however calling gulp is failed from Teamcity service  (which is running under Windows's account Local System).

[image]

To reproduce, I am using psexe from PSTools (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553) to open cmd with local system account:

[image]

I can run npm

[image]

but get the error when executing gulp globally

[image]

**NOTE:**

i can execute the local gulp by going to the project folder and run `node_modules\.bin\gulp.cmd -v`

[image]

Any idea pls?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp

Comment: tried NODE_PATH without luck. did u try with local system account?