# "gulp -v" command not working

Tags: node.js, gulp

I am working on Windows 7. I have installed node and have been working with node and tsc for a while now with out issues.

the c:\users\username\appdata\roaming\npm path is already set in my environment variable and the command "node" works from any folder location in the command prompt with out issues.

I installed gulp using the following command
"npm install -g gulp"

and the installation was successful.

But when I run "gulp -v" command from the appData folder its working fine as follows

[Running gulp from AppData folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqWG1.jpg)

And when I run outside the AppData folder it is throwing errors as illustrated in the following screenshot :(

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCc8c.jpg)

I have searched the forum for answers but did not get any. Am having a hard time figuring this out.Please help me with this.

Comment: the links open to screen shots of associated information. Expected them to appear here but are appearing as links :(

Comment: good solution that I've solved my problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/24042936/7719852

Comment: Another workaround is to have gulp as part of your dependencies and then use the local gulp executable; it will probably be in `./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp`. You can create a shortcut for this via a npm script!

Comment: Thank you Firat. That helped. In addition I had a file named gulp.js which was also causing an issue. I renamed it to gulpfile.js instead and that resolved the issue. Thanks again :)