# Stylus, gulp is not recognized ... cmd

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, installation, stylus

I installed Node.js and type install stylus and gulp success. But when I call gulp or stylus... they aren't not run.

I tried chance path in regedit and add Enviroment by: [gulp command not found - error after installing gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp).

Doesn't work :(( in win 10. My path: C:\Users\Chung Phung\AppData\Roaming\npm.

I can not solve it 2 days :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For gulp, try install gulp-cli globally,

```
npm install -g gulp-cli
```

For stylus, try restart your command window.

Comment: I have solve about path enviroment, I installed but I no see have file, folder in npm folder.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you clearly, but if you are trying to find stylus or gulp you installed, you can use `npm ls -g --depth=0` to list all packages you installed globally.

Comment: C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local

+-- gulp@3.9.1

+-- gulp-cli@1.3.0

+-- npm@5.3.0

`-- stylus@0.54.5