# Gulp not recognized in command prompt despite updated added path variable

Tags: node.js, gulp

I installed gulp following the [standard procedure](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/docs/getting-started.md):

```
$ npm install --global gulp-cli
```

adding the project dev dependency

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

and a `gulpfile.js`

When running `gulp` from Git Bash I get the error `gulp: command not found`

I followed [related threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp) here on SO updating my path variable (Windows 7) with C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm to no avail

I actually didn't find any gulp folders inside C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm (other packages are still there and function as expected). Instead, gulp seems to get installed to C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local

Running `npm root` and `npm root -g` respectively, return
C:\Users\username\node_modules and 
C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\node_modules

I also got the following warnings when running `npm install --save-dev gulp`
[image]

I feel like I mixed up paths somehow, but I'm a bit lost, as I'm new to Node and Gulp.

Comment: `npm uninstall -g gulp` and then `npm install -g gulp`

Answer (score -1):

After open command shell with administrator simply write npm install -g gulp and npm install -g gulp-cli. You can reach from every location to gulp then.

Comment: Did you exit the shell and load again?

Comment: Yes, I also tried this several times and used different shells. Is Gulp getting installed to C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local expected behavior on Windows? I'm asking, because it sits there alone. Other modules like browser_sync reside in a totally different place.

Comment: That's nonsense i dont know why this happened. Ok try to add as an environment variables.

Comment: So, I do get a response to gulp -v when adding C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local to PATH (I was using C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\nodes_modules before). The response returns "CLI version" btw. I still wonder, why Gulp ist the only modul that gets installed in this very place

Comment: You should add in system env that PATH.