# All of sudden gulp command not recognizing in spfx solution

Tags: npm, gulp, spfx

Solution type: SharePoint SPFx

I made windows update on this Sunday. From that point, I am not able to execute gulp commands. I am not sure if there is any relation between windows update and gulp command. I am getting below error.

[image]
I have installed gulp again by `npm install gulp -g`. I have restarted my machine and tried. But still same issue. I have added this in environment variables also. 
[image]

I have followed all the instructions explained in [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027551/gulp-command-not-found-error-after-installing-gulp/41419949) but no resolution found.

After installation of gulp globally when I run below command it is not list me gulp
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the local packages, but you should check the global:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```