# How does a JNI DLL search for its dependent native DLL?

Tags: java, c++, dll, java-native-interface, dynamic-linking

Say I have `JNI.dll`. It depends on `native.dll`. Now my Java application calls `System.loadLibrary("JNI")`.

Will the following folder layout work?

```
MainFolder
    |--main.exe
    |--SubFolder
          |--JNI.dll
          |--native.dll
```

My guess is, there are **2 levels** of dependency resolution.

[Level 1]:

`System.loadLibrary("JNI")` uses JVM property `java.library.path` to locate `JNI.dll`.

[Level 2]:

`JNI.dll` relies on Windows system mechanism to locate `native.dll`.

Is this correct?

If I set `%_JAVA_OPTIONS%` as `-Djava.library.path=MainFolder\SubFolder`, I think it can cover the search for `JNI.dll`. **But will it cover the search for `native.dll`, too?**

### ADD 1

It seems my guess of 2 levels got confirmed from here: [How to add native library to "java.library.path" with Eclipse launch (instead of overriding it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661320/how-to-add-native-library-to-java-library-path-with-eclipse-launch-instead-of)

See comment by *kevin cline*. But the mentioned solution with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable only applies to Linux.

### ADD 2

I think I didn't make my question clear. Let me put it this way.

My confusion is: the `JNI.dll` depends on `native.dll`. **Both** of them are **not** in the `main.exe`'s current working directory. Actually they are in a sub folder of CWD.

If I run `main.exe` directly, I just need to set the `java.library.path = <other path>\MainFolder\SubFolder`. Both DLL are found correctly.

But if I run my project from Eclipse, **besides** setting the `java.library.path`, I have to put the "\MainFolder\SubFolder" in the %PATH% environment variable.

I just don't know why Eclipse is so different.

Comment: The same way it does `a.dll`. See [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586.aspx). It's always relative to the EXE doing the loading.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry for the lack of the background. I updated my question.

Comment: You can modify `PATH` environment variable (just for your process) and add `MainFolder\SubFolder` to it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Will Windows automatically look for native.dll in the same folder as JNI.dll? I don't want to modify the PATH.

Comment: I'm 95% sure it will not. Should be easy to determine experimentally.

Comment: JNI doesn't search for DLLs. The operating system does, and the rules are the same for all.

Comment: @EJP But I remember that `java.library.path` is used for locating the native libraries. Isn't it meant for JNI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar link: [Must I place all dependent DLLs into the JDK's bin folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891114/must-i-place-all-dependent-dlls-into-the-jdks-bin-folder)

Inspired by this thread:[System versus user PATH environmental variable...winmerge works only if I add the path to the user PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270267/system-versus-user-path-environmental-variable-winmerge-works-only-if-i-add-th)

I start to wonder maybe my User %Path% is **too long**. So I moved the folder path containing my dependent DLL from the **end** of User %PATH% to the **beginning**. It works now!

At first, I conclude that one who implemented the Windows' DLL lookup algorithm has some truncation issue. And I *almost* consider it as another annoying Windows Bug.

But I wrote another Windows application which has similar DLL dependencies to confirm my guess. That application works fine! So I have to review my conclusion.

I checked my User %PATH% entry one by one, and place the folder to each possible location. And finally, I find the **root cause**.

> I have a `C:\MinGW\bin` entry in User %PATH%, which happens to contain a
>   `libstdc++-6.dll (977KB)` but unfortunately, which isn't compatible
>   with the one I need `(825KB)`. It only works if I place my folder before MinGW.

Now this issue seems resolved. But another one comes up, do I need to switch back and forth if I want to use both my DLL and the MinGW?

Answer (score 2):

1)It searches in the current Directory.

2)System folder typically C:\Windows\System32 (use CSIDL_SYSTEM with `shgetspecialfolderpath()`  to get the rigth folder on the given system)

3)Windows folder (C:\Windows )(CSIDL_WINDOWS with `shgetspecialfolderpath()` to get the right folder on the given system)

4)All the folders listed under PAth environmnet variable