# 'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command in Windows 7

Tags: java, windows, ant

I am trying to set up the apache ANT in Windows7 and executed below commands in cmd.

```
set ANT_HOME=c:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.9
set JAVA_HOME=c:\Softwares\jdk7x64
set PATH=%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```

But, when i execute **ant -version** command it gives me below error. I cannot set the path from environment variables as i don't have admin rights to do so. How can i do it through command prompt only. What is wrong here ?

**Error**

```
'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
```

If i give below command

```
echo %ANT_HOME%
```

i get the output as

```
 c:\Softwares\apache-ant-1.9
```

Comment: You should still be able to set as a user level environment variable without admin permissions, however as pointed out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270267/system-versus-user-path-environmental-variable-winmerge-works-only-if-i-add-th if your System level path is too long the user path and system path won't merge

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the PATH variable as below?

```
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;
```