# Windows CMD Shorten file path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I got Gnu Utilities that adds the command `sed` to windows, but to use it I have to type:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe <args>
```

How do I shorten this to just `sed <args>`?

Answer (score 2):

To run an executable without a full path, it needs to be either in the current directory, or in the `PATH` environment variable.  In the CMD prompt, there are several ways to do this.

The first way is to put `C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin` in your PATH variable, which makes every program in that directory available without a full path.

```
set "PATH=%path%;C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin"
```

This updates PATH in the current command prompt.  If you need to set it for other CMD windows, see [How to persistently set a variable in Windows 7 from a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6523979/821878)

The second method is to have `sed.exe` in the current directory.  The most obvious way to do that is to change directories.

```
cd C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin
sed
```

Or you can copy it to your current directory.

```
copy C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe .\
sed
```

(This works with `sed.exe` because it's a self-contained utility.  Don't try this with a Windows application like `excel.exe`)

Finally, you can create a "redirect" somewhere in the current directory or the path.

```
>.\sed.bat echo C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe %*
```

This creates a batch file in the current directory called `sed.bat` that calls the full `sed.exe`.  You can drop this file into any directory in your `PATH`.

```
mklink .\sed.exe C:\ProgramFiles\GnuWin32\bin\sed.exe
```

This creates a symlink to the `sed.exe` in the current directory, much like a symlink in Unix or a shortcut in Windows.